# How can I have two distinct inputs in keras layer?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, concatenation, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to replicate the neural networtk architecture of the **ExpertModel** in AI4Animation ([Github](https://github.com/sebastianstarke/AI4Animation/tree/master/AI4Animation/SIGGRAPH_2020/DeepLearning/Models/ExpertModel)) in TensorFlow 2.

I have two neural networks with identical (dense) layers, the only difference being that the first (let's call it the gating network) uses its output to modulate the weights of the second network (by blending the weights). Note that the second network has a distinct input. So I need to have two inputs for the second network, let's call them "**Input**" and "**weight_blend**". I also need to be able to backpropegate to both x and back to the input of the gating network.

Basically what I want is this:

[image]

I first tried to just pass `weight_blend` as an attribute to some layers. I could define the models of the two networks just fine, however I couldn't connect the two  since keras didn't see weight_blend as an input variable (I think). This makes sense to me, so I tried the following:

My second attempt, I tried to pass weight_blend as a second input alongside the main input x. However this turned out to be worse. My gating model is defined just fine, however when I pass the weight_blend variable to the second network, backpropegation fails altogether, not even for the second network's distinct input.

This is how I call the custom dense layer where the weight blending happens:

```
def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):

    x = inputs[0]
    weight_blend = inputs[1]

    # get_NNweight/bias just return the initialized weight based on the weight_blend coefficient
    self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=self.experts.get_NNweight(weight_blend, self.batch_size),
                         trainable=True)
    self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=self.experts.get_NNbias(weight_blend, self.batch_size),
                         trainable=True)

    x = tf.matmul(self.w, x) + self.b

    acti = self.activation
    if acti != 0:
        if acti == tf.nn.softmax:
            x = acti(x, axis=1)
        else:
            x = acti(x)
    return x
```

This is the gating network (I just pass an initialized version of the weights here):

[image]

I am very reluctant to use a Concatenate layer, because I am using my two inputs for completely different things, plus the inputs have very different shapes. How can I merge the two networks so I can define the whole thing as one trainable model by just calculating the loss of the main network's output?

Answer (score 0):

I was making two mistakes:

1)I was training the weights AFTER the blend happens. I should be training the weights that are defined before the blending occurs.

2)The final model consists of two inputs, both the gating input and the main input.